# Send copy of a script's output to a file

Tags: shell-script, zsh, io-redirection, pipe, output

Say I have a Zsh script and that I would like to let it print output to `STDOUT`, but also copy (dump) its output to a file in disk.

Moreover, the script starts with the following option

```
set -o xtrace
```

which forces it to be verbose and print what commands it runs. I would like to capture this output as well in a file in disk.

My understanding is that if I do

```
./my_script.sh > log.txt
```

it will just send `STDOUT` to `log.txt`, but what if I want to also be able to see the output in the terminal?

I have read about `tee` and the [`MULTIOS`](http://www.refining-linux.org/archives/41/ZSH-Gem-6-Redirect-output-to-multiple-files/) option in Zsh, but am not sure how to use them.

When I do:

```
./my_script | tee log.txt
```

I can see the output on the terminal, but the file `log.txt` doesn'tseem to be capturing everything (in fact it captures barely anything).

Comment: `./my_script.sh > log.txt 2>&1`

Comment: Looks like you're looking for the `script` command. Or maybe `myscript >&1 > log.txt 2>&1`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It could be that your script is producing output to `stdout` and `stderr`, and you are only getting one of those streams output to your log file.

`./my_script.sh | tee log.txt` will indeed output everything to the terminal, but will only dump `stdout` to the logfile.

`./my_script.sh > log.txt 2>&1` will do the opposite, dumping everything to the log file, but displaying nothing on screen.

The trick is to combine the two with `tee`:

```
./myscript.sh 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

This redirects `stderr` (`2`) into `stdout` (`1`), then pipes `stdout` into `tee`, which copies it to the terminal **and** to the log file.

The `zsh` multios equivalent would be:

```
./myscript.sh >&1 > log.txt 2>&1
```

That is, redirect stdout both to the original stdout and log.txt (internally via a pipe to something that works like `tee`), and then redirect stderr to that as well (to the pipe to the internal `tee`-like process).

Comment: Thanks -- Regarding your last line, why not `./myscript.sh >&1 2>&1 > log.txt` ? (i.e. switching the order of the last two redirections). Would there be any difference between them?

Comment: Your variant does not output onto `stdout`, just to `log.txt`. The last line in the answer (added by @StéphaneChazelas and not myself) outputs to both.

Answer (score 1):

nohup allows a job to carry on even if the console dies or is closed, useful for lengthy backups etc, but here we are using its automatic logging.

```
nohup myscript.sh & ; tail -f nohup.out
```